# apache htaccess to nginx config error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I have a htaccess with the following content:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

I was able to convert it using 2 online tools but if I put them in my nginx config file then it refuses to start.

http://winginx.com/en/htaccess gives the following output:

```
# nginx configuration index index.php;
location / {
rewrite ^(.*)//(.*)$ /%1/%2 redirect;
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&$query_string break; 
} 
}
```

http://www.anilcetin.com/ gives the following output:

```
if ($uri ~ "^(.*)//(.*)$"){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
    set $bref_1 $1;
    set $bref_2 $2;
}
if ($rule_0 = "1"){
    rewrite /. /$bref_1/$bref_2 permanent;
}
if (!-f $request_filename){
    set $rule_1 1$rule_1;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
    set $rule_1 2$rule_1;
}
if ($rule_1 = "21"){
    rewrite ^/.*$ /index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&$args last;
}
```

I tried both of them but it seems to have some error and nginx refuses to start after a restart.

Anyone? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The htaccess file has three elements.

The first is covered by the `index` directive.

The second performs a permanent redirect in order to remove any double slash `//` in the URL. This is difficult to implement with `nginx` because it normalises the URL. Although the variable `$request_uri` contains the raw value, the variable `$uri` contains the normalised value. One would need to understand where the `//` causes a problem in order to find the optimum solution. However, the use of `$uri` below means that any redirect may be unnecessary.

The third is commonly handled by the `try_files` directive.

Assuming that the htaccess file is at the top of the document root, try:

```
location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?qa-rewrite=$uri&$args;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation and your answer answer like a charm. Cheers.